# Populating Spinner with SimpleAdapter in Android

Tags: android, spinner, simpleadapter

I have used ArrayAdapter to populate the Spinner. I want to know if it can be done using a SimpleAdapter? Please guide me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383913/using-simpleadapter-with-spinner/4384000#4384000) (including the follow-up comments) is correct, then you may need to add a [ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html) to the `SimpleAdapter`. You can google for examples of `ViewBinder` implementations -- it doesn't seem to be very complicated.

---

EDIT: You do need the ViewBinder, at least for some earlier versions of AndroidOS (I found it's not needed for 2.2). See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383913/using-simpleadapter-with-spinner/4384000#4384000), and perhaps also my [blog post](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-spinners-simpleadapter-and-maybe-viewbinder/) about this.

Comment: Thanks dude. Thats really helpful. You got "Accepted Answer" two times for the same answer. ;-) Anyway, can you please tell me how did you figured out that the code is not working on Android 1.6? Do you test every code on every version?

Comment: Thanks. Hey, I'd have settled for an uprate on the other answer :-) Anyway: no, I didn't test every version of the OS -- in fact, I only have emulators set up for 1.5 and 2.2, and I simply tested the code with those two versions. So, I don't know which version of the OS first fixed the problem.